# Accessibility implications of using a button instead of a link

Tags: html, web, accessibility

I'm working on a client project which acts as a resource and support system for vulnerable people. Accessibility compliance has been touted as the absolute highest priority for this site because of the expected users, so we're currently working to meet [WCAG 2.0 Level AA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/) as closely as possible.

Currently the code for the login/registration links in the header looks like this:

```
<div class="profile-summary">
    <a class="profile-summary__link" href="/login">Login</a>
    or
    <a class="profile-summary__link" href="/register">sign up</a>
</div>
```

Another developer who is working on the user management system wants to change the login link to be a form containing a submit button. Something (hypothetically) like this:

```
<div class="profile-summary">
    <form action="/login" method="get">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    or
    <a class="profile-summary__link" href="/register">sign up</a>
</div>
```

This doesn't really sit well with me and it seems like something screenreaders and other assistive software will trip over (e.g. won't read the login option when summarising the page). To my knowledge some of these switch into a 'form mode' when they encounter a form, which would be jarring in this situation.

Are there any detrimental accessibility implications to using a form and button over a plain link in this context?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the developer want to change it? May it be the case that the developer wants to include the login fields, too (i.e., for name and password)?

Comment: AFAIK they want it to be a form so they can pass a token along, but I fail to see why this couldn't just be a query string parameter, personally.

Answer (score 5):

In this context, the link with `href="#"` is right out.

Adding a form can be more confusing than anything because it implies a different thing will happen between each of two otherwise similar controls. A form with no fields and only a button is even more confusing to many SR users. That may be a bigger problem than the links.

Remember that [not all screen reader users are blind](http://adrianroselli.com/2017/02/not-all-screen-reader-users-are-blind.html), so if these controls look the same but behave differently that is also an issue.

Without seeing what these two controls do, it is hard to offer specific advice about which element is the right choice.

Here is generally the way I approach this question...

### Does the Control Take Me to Another Page? Use an Anchor

If, when clicked, tapped, or activated by keyboard or voice (or insert novel interaction method here), the user is whisked to another URL (including an anchor on the same page), then use [`<a href="[URL]">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Make sure you use the [`href`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href) attribute and that it has a real URL, not a “#” (otherwise you’re probably relying on JavaScript, which is not at all necessary for a hyperlink). If an `href` points to just a “#”, then you’re probably doing it wrong. If it points to a named anchor as part of your progressive enhancement efforts, then that’s totally valid.

### Does the Control Change Something on the Current Page? Use a Button

If, when activated, the user is not moved from the page (or to an anchor within the page), but instead is presented with a new view (message boxes, changes in layout, etc.), then use a [`<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element). While you could use an `<input type="button">`, it’s more likely you’ll get into conflicts with pre-existing styles and subsequent developers (like me).

### Does the Control Submit Form Fields? Use a Submit

If, when activated, information the user has entered (either by manually typing or by choosing items on the screen) is being sent back to the server, then use an [`<input type="submit">`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type). This had better live within a `<form>`. If you need more styling control or have to embed more than just a simple text string, use a `<button type="submit">` instead. I tend to prefer `<input type="submit">` as I find it runs into fewer conflicts (both mentally and stylistically) with developers.

### Keyboard User Consideration

Think of keyboard users for a moment. A hyperlink can be fired by pressing the enter key. But a true button can be fired by pressing the enter key or the space bar. When a hyperlink has focus and the user presses the space bar, the page will scroll one screenful. If there isn’t more to scroll then the user just experiences nothing. Given a set of interface elements that look the same, if some work with a space bar and some don’t, you can’t expect users to have much confidence in how the page behaves.

I have a CodePen demo that shows this in action: http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/PZQJyd

I think it’s also worth mentioning that events triggered by a space bar only fire when the key is released, whereas using the Enter key will fire the event as soon as you press the key down (prior to releasing it).

For reference: http://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html

Comment: Ah whoops, the `href="#"` in the snippets is just my bad; these *will* be linking off to other pages. With that in mind, do you feel links make more sense than buttons?

Comment: Heck yes. If you are not submitting form information, then a link is the right course of action. It exposes the URL to the user in a way that a form will not. Frankly, the form is hostile IMO in this context.

Comment: I see you edited your post to adjust those link URLs. Those were not there when I first answered, so mentally adjust my answer accordingly please.